# Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'UserId'

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Here is my class code, where I am getting the error as :
(1). `Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'UserId'.` - do not able to understand the issue. please needs the clarification.

component.ts:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

interface Identical<T extends number | string> {
  id: T;
}

interface UserId {
  id: number;
}

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements Identical<UserId> {
  id: UserId;
  title = "CodeSandbox";
  constructor(id: number) {
    this.id = id;
  }
}
```

in my case,  (2) I require to pass the `id` to the class. what is the best practice to handle that?

[LIVE DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/class-with-return-type-zr19j?file=/src/app/app.component.ts:0-405)

Comment: `interface Identical` does not accept `UserId` type, So you could do `interface Identical<T extends number | string | UserId>` or just `AppComponent implements Identical<number>`

Comment: Is this helps https://codesandbox.io/s/class-with-return-type-forked-q1f6l?file=/src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

`this.id` is pointing to a type `UserId`. But you want to pass the value to `id`inside `UserId`.

`this.id.id = id` -> Try this.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can declare the id variable to number as below.

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

interface Identical<T extends number | string> {
  id: T;
}

interface UserId {
  id: number;
}

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  public id: UserId = { id: 5 };
  title = "CodeSandbox";
  constructor() {
    this.id.id = 7;
    // This may fix your issue.
    // Bcs you have declared the `UserId` interface as Object.
  }
}
```

In order to pass the id value to the component, you can use input value.

[Live demo](https://codesandbox.io/embed/github/JaiSaro/stackoverflow-69503683/tree/main/?expanddevtools=1&fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&initialpath=%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts&module=%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts&theme=dark) for fixing the above issue.

Comment: Your are not implemented the interface at all

Comment: I have updated my solution kindly check.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are expecting `T` to be number or string

```
interface Identical<T extends number | string> {
  id: T;
}
```

But in you example you are passing an interface which is does'nt fit the condition.

```
implements Identical<UserId>
```

Pass into `Identical` just `number` or `string` type

```
interface Identical<T extends number | string> {
  id: T;
}


@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements Identical<number> {
  id: number; // change to number
  title = "CodeSandbox";
  constructor(id: number) {
    this.id = id;
  }
}
```